# Java returning null value from method

Tags: java

I keep having a object come up as `null` for `Elf 1` which is supposed to show `BEST FRIEND: HOBBIT 2` but it only shows `null`. I tried to look for solutions but nothing helped me. Would anyone please help me figure out a solution? Thank you.

example output:

`ELF 1 [ STATUS: Alive Elf ] [ CLAN: Forest | BEST FRIEND: null ] [ STR: 5 | DEX: 7 | ARM: 1 | MOX: 16 ] [ COINS: 77 | HEALTH: 80 ]`

`ELF 2 [ STATUS: Alive Elf ] [ CLAN: City | BEST FRIEND: HOBBIT 1 ] [ STR: 14 | DEX: 20 | ARM: 18 | MOX: 12 ] [ COINS: 1000 | HEALTH: 80 ]`

main class

```
        // HOBBIT 1 AND 2
        System.out.println("\nLet's create new two Hobbits!");
        System.out.println("Building two new hobbits...");
        System.out.println("\nHobbit 1 name: ");
        String hobbitName = sc.nextLine();
        Hobbit hobbit1 = new Hobbit(hobbitName);

        System.out.println("Hobbit 2 name: ");
        String hobbitName2 = sc.nextLine();
        Hobbit hobbit2 = new Hobbit(hobbitName2, 8, 12, 2, 14, 10, 30);
        System.out.println("\n" + hobbit1);
        System.out.println(hobbit2);

        // ELF 1 AND 2
        System.out.println("\nLet's create new two Elves!");
        System.out.println("Building two new Elves...");
        System.out.println("\nElf 1 name: ");
        String elfName1 = sc.nextLine();
        Elf elf1 = new Elf(elfName1);

        System.out.println("Elf 2 name: ");
        String elfName2 = sc.nextLine();
        Elf elf2 = new Elf(elfName2, 14, 20, 18, 12, 1000, 80, "Forest", hobbit1);
        System.out.println("\n" + elf1);
        System.out.println(elf2);
```

code in elf class

````
public class Elf extends Humanoid {

    private final String clan;    
    private String bestFriend;   

    public Elf(String name) {
        super(name);

        // randomly sets clan
        Random random = new Random();
        if(random.nextBoolean()){
            clan = "Forest";
        } else {
            clan = "City";
        }
    }

    public Elf(String name, String clan, Hobbit bestFriend) {
        super(name);
        this.clan = clan;
        this.bestFriend = bestFriend.getName();
    }

    public Elf(String name, int strength, int dexterity, int armour, int moxie, int coins, int healthRating, String clan, Hobbit bestFriend) {
        super(name, strength, dexterity, armour, moxie, coins, healthRating);
        this.clan = clan;
        this.bestFriend = bestFriend.getName();
    }

    public String getBestFriend() {
        return this.bestFriend;
    }

    public void setBestFriend(Hobbit bestFriend) {
        this.bestFriend = bestFriend.getName();
    }

    public String getClan() {
        return clan;
    }
    // only for elf 2 line
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName() +
                " [ STATUS: " + super.isAlive() +
                " Elf ] [ CLAN: " + clan +
                " | BEST FRIEND: " + getBestFriend() +
                " ]" + super.toString();
    }
}```
````

Comment: Please do not delete the content of the question like you did. Please revert the changes so that @ErnestFriedman-Hill 's answer is not left out in the cold. And do not even think about deleting this question, as it might help somebody else.

Answer (score 2):

You’re calling the constructor `Elf(String)` to create elf1; this constructor sets the clan and the name and that’s all. Nothing ever sets the “best friend” so it remains null.

Comment: Are you writing or modifying the “Elf” class? You need to add another constructor parameter to that one-argument constructor so you can pass the best friend, like the other constructors have, and then add a line of code in the constructor to actually set the member variable.